# Conditional probability by joint probability

Tags: probability

I have the joint pdf $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{5}(3xy^2+2x^3y);0<x<1;0<y<2$$ and I have to calculate $$P(\frac{1}{2}<Y|X<\frac{1}{2})$$

I have found that $$f_{X}(x)=\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{5}(3xy^2+2x^3y)dy=\frac{1}{5}(24x+4x^3)$$ and, I know that $$f_{y|X=x} =\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$$

But, what can I do if I have $X<x$ instead of $X=x$?

Answer (score 4):

$\{X<\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $\{Y>\frac{1}{2}\}$ are events, hence 
$$ \mathbb{P}\Big(Y>\frac{1}{2}\mid X<\frac{1}{2}\Big)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X<\frac{1}{2},Y>\frac{1}{2})}{\mathbb{P}(X<\frac{1}{2})}$$
and these two probabilities can be computed using the joint pdf.

Comment: I think i have some problem with my $f_{X}(x)$.
bacause $\int_{0}^{1} f_{X}(x) \neq 1$.
Do you see the problem ?

Comment: I think it should be $f_X(x)=\frac{8}{5}x+\frac{4}{5}x^3$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: You right, my bad.
So $P(X<{\frac{1}{2}}) =  \int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}\:\left(\frac{1}{5}\left(8x+4x^3\right)\right)dx = \frac{17}{80}$

But how can i calculate $\fracP(X<\frac{1}{2},Y>\frac{1}{2})}$

Comment: You can find it by integrating the joint pdf over the region $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{2}<y<2$.

Comment: i got you.
Thanks !